# Book or resources to learn about algorithms for detecting arbitrage opportunities in slow markets (not HFT)

Tags: algorithms, finance

All of the trading algorithms I see online relate to high-frequency trading in fast-moving high-volume markets.

Can someone point me to some resources about automated trading (detecting arbitrage opportunities) in lower-volume and lower-velocity markets such as eBay?

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94414/an-algorithm-for-arbitrage-in-currency-exchange

Answer (score 1):

Firstly such a reference request here may be off topic. Also i am not sure if it possible  to do arbitrage in e-bay system unless you know what is the current price for an item to be bought in different sub-ebay systems(ebay of different countries). I am unsure as a seller what information is available to you. Arbitrage could only be done when there is known price u can buy at and a known price u can sell the goods at in different ebay markets, also this would not necessarily be completely risk free, as you might be open to exchange rate movements. Also to classify as arbitrage it has to be an instantaneous transaction without holding the merchandise or goods on your own book. Secondly in case of e-bay transaction you may end up needing to ship, which may introduce additional costs, some what analogous to transaction costs probably, but may be much higher in proportion (u may be able to control this by trading in only goods with low shipping costs, so no cars and couches perhaps). This may reduce the chance further of arbitrage unless the person you bought from was selling it at a much lower price than the current market price and the person who is buying is willing to buy probably at a much higher price.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. EBay was just an example of a "slower" market. I just want to learn the abstract concepts and algorithms.

Perhaps arbitrage was too specific a word. More generally my question is:

Given full information about a market (similar to the stock market with Google Finance, but much slower than the stock market), I would like to learn about algorithms that identify opportunities for buying and selling to make a profit.

Comment: i think u would find better responses to your query at http://quant.stackexchange.com/
Good Luck !

Comment: There's something wrong with your keyboard. It somehow fails to register the two first letters of the word "you" each time you type it. Very annoying -- please fix it or replace the keyboard.

Comment: @HenningMakholm lol, thanks that was funny, did n't know it could bother some one that much.lol I shall try keep that in mind for future.