# Dead simple arbitrage algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

When googling for a solution to the currency arbitrage problem, a variant of the [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm comes up as the most efficient solution. See for example [this page](https://www.dailycodingproblem.com/blog/how-to-find-arbitrage-opportunities-in-python) or this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94414).

Trying to solve the problem with a friend, we came up with what we think is a simpler solution with the same $O(n^3)$ time complexity that does not involve any fancy names like Bellman-Ford. We are not sure however that our solution is indeed correct (seems a bit simple) and wanted your help to have it proof-read in case something escaped us. Thanks in advance for your help.

I describe the solution below and attached the complete (dead simple) algorithm in python at the end of this post.

---

An [arbitrage](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/arbitrage.asp) opportunity occurs when you can exchange a currency into another and repeat the process until you end up with more of the initial currency in your hands.

In the following, we denote $r_{ab}$ the exchange rate between currency $A$ and currency $B$. To avoid simple aribtrage opportunities, we should at least have $r_{ab} r_{ba} = 1$.

Let's now assume no arbitrage opportunity exists using three or fewer currencies but that there is one for four currencies, that is $A \to B \to C \to D \to A$ leads to an increase in currency $A$. Then we should have

$$ r_{ab} r_{bc} r_{cd} r_{da} \gt 1. \tag 1 $$

Moreover, because $A \to B \to C \to A$ involves only three currencies, there is no possible arbitrage and thus

$$ r_{ab} r_{bc} r_{ca} = 1. \tag 2 $$

Similarly,

$$ r_{ac} r_{ca} = 1. \tag 3 $$

From (1) and (2), we can write:

$$ r_{cd} r_{da} > r_{ca}. \tag 4 $$

And using (3), we have $r_{cd} r_{da} r_{ac} > 1$, leading to the arbitrage with three currencies $C \to D \to A \to C$.

I believe we can use the same method to recursively prove that if there is a possible arbitrage with $n+1$ (where $n \geq 3$) currencies, there should be an arbitrage with $n$ currencies.

Using the above proof, we should be able to safely say that, if there is no arbitrage with three or fewer currencies, then there is no arbitrage at all.

Therefore, a simple algorithm to check for the existence of arbitrage would be as follow (with $r$ the exchange rate matrix and $n$ the number of currencies available):

```
def arbitrage(r):
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
      for k in range(n):
        if r[i, j] * r[j, k] * r[k, i] > 1:
          return True
  return False
```

Is there something we missed?

Comment: Surely you don't get equality to 1; rather, 1 is a maximum.

Comment: The link to Daily Coding Problem is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is clearly wrong: you can only conclude that 2/3-cycles evaluate to $\leq 1$. In your example the only way to add in a cycle is to multiply with something that closes a cycle (like $r_{ca}$) but then you have to divide it out and you are back at the beginning. Multiplying with $r_{ca}r_{ac}$ does not work as this is $\leq 1$ in general and thus the inequality goes in the wrong direction.

Comment: I see thanks @b00n heT. Would the proof hold if we can exchange currency pairs back and forth without a loss (ie $r_{ac} = 1/r_{ca}$)?

Comment: If you have such a currency, then you can squeeze it in a currency exchange cycle and indeed prove your result: if you have a $n$ cycle and your “spread-free” currency appears in position $k$, then you can split the $n$ cycle in a $n-k+1$ and a $k+1$ cycle. $4$ cycles are thus splittable iff your spread free currency is in position 2 or 3.